# How can I ensure that all assets are loaded in React?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm currently working on a project where I have a specific requirement. I want all assets on my page, including images, videos, and fonts, to only render once they are completely loaded. This requirement is to ensure a smoother user experience and minimize render blocking.

Here's my current solution using React and FontFaceObserver:

```js
"use client";

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import FontFaceObserver from "fontfaceobserver";
import { AssetLoaderView } from "~/sections/asset-loader.tsx";

const PUBLIC_PATH = "/assets";

export const AssetLoaderProvider = ({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
  const [currentFile, setCurrentFile] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadAssets = async () => {
      const images = [
        "icons/home/ic_discord.svg",
        "icons/home/ic_medium.svg",
        "icons/home/ic_twitter.svg",
        "videos/main.gif",
        "placeholder.svg",
        "transparent.png",
      ];
      const fonts: any[] = [];
      const videos: any[] = [];

      const assets = [...images, ...fonts, ...videos];

      const assetPromises = assets.map(
        (asset, index) =>
          new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setCurrentFile(asset);
            setProgress((index / assets.length) * 100);

            let element;

            if (images.includes(asset)) {
              element = new Image();
              element.src = `${PUBLIC_PATH}/${asset}`;
            } else if (videos.includes(asset)) {
              element = document.createElement("video");
              element.src = `${PUBLIC_PATH}/${asset}`;
              element.oncanplaythrough = resolve;
              element.onerror = reject;
            } else {
              new FontFaceObserver(`${PUBLIC_PATH}/${asset}`)
                .load()
                .then(resolve, reject);
              return;
            }

            element.onload = resolve;
            element.onerror = reject;
          })
      );

      await Promise.all(assetPromises);
      setProgress(100);
      setLoading(false);
    };

    loadAssets();
  }, []);

  if (loading)
    return <AssetLoaderView filename={currentFile} progress={progress} />;

   return children;
};
```

This code effectively waits for all assets to be loaded before rendering them. It uses promises to handle the loading of each asset, and tracks the progress of the overall loading process.

However, while testing, I've noticed an issue. Upon monitoring the network activities, I observed that my SVG icons are trying to fetch twice. Even though they are fetched from the cache during the second request, it's still a redundant process. I'm wondering if this indicates that there's something wrong with my approach.

I came across this website, https://kprverse.com, which seems to be doing exactly what I want to achieve. I'd appreciate it if you could guide me on how I can optimize my current approach, or suggest a better method to achieve this.

Here is a screenshot of the network activities showing the issue:

[image: screenshot]

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea for user experience to only show the preloader (AssetLoaderView component is a preloader?) until all images are downloaded. I believe that using blurHash or a skeleton would be better.

However, I'm not entirely sure about your case. In development mode, the useEffect function run twice. To address this, you could try creating a state called 'initial' and setting it to false after the promise completes

Comment: yes that's true. AssetLoaderView component that functions as a preloader now. User experience is in the background right now. I want all assets to be ready when the user loads the page, otherwise it will cause a very bad display.